# Strange checksum256->uint64_t casting

Tags: smart-contract, development, contract-development

I'm trying to cast checksum256 to uint64_t

Here is conversion code:

```
uint64_t checksum_to_uint64(const eosio::checksum256 & digest) {
        auto checksum_bytes = digest.extract_as_byte_array().data();
        uint64_t result = reinterpret_cast<uint64_t>(&checksum_bytes);
        return result;
}
```

But when I try to pass hashes of strings of the same length there, this function produces the same numbers

example:

`sha256(d83631286d922f747aaee529d86cb566)` converts to 49
`sha256(7dc0cc92aa96cf8e8909cbe5468c1b4d)` converts to 49
`sha256(b97280a2a88868684dca726570435c96)` converts to 49

Can anybody explain this to me

Comment: The type of `checksum_bytes` is `uint8_t*`, and you're trying to convert `uint8_t**` (`&checksum_bytes`) to `uint64_t`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know where the 49 comes from but you are doing a reinterpret_cast from `std::array<uint8_t,32>` which is **256 bit** to `uint64_t` which is **64 bit** - this doesn't not seem like a good idea in principle.

Are these values real, tested examples?

> sha256(d83631286d922f747aaee529d86cb566) converts to 49
>   sha256(7dc0cc92aa96cf8e8909cbe5468c1b4d) converts to 49
>   sha256(b97280a2a88868684dca726570435c96) converts to 49

To ensure to know what's happening in the background, I'd personally (except I wouldn't truncate a 256-bit hash to 64 bits) use `memcpy` for what you want to achieve.

```
auto checksum_bytes = digest.extract_as_byte_array().data();
uint64_t x;
std::memcpy(&x, &checksum_bytes, sizeof(x));
```